# if_else with multiple else conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, dplyr

`year <- 1900:2017`

`source <- 1:118`

I have to mutate a new column such that if `source == 1, then new_column == 1900, if source == 2, new_column == 1901` and so on.

i tried

`new_column <- if_else(source == 1, 1900, if_else(source == 2, 1901, if_else(x == 3, 1903,))` ... and so on.

But I cannot continue for `source == 118`. Any other way to do this?

Comment: `d$e <- d$c+1899` or `d %>% mutate(e = c +1899)`

Comment: Why don't you do `c + 1899`?

Comment: For other uses that are not linearly related like this, you might prefer `dplyr::case_when`, a far better alternative to nested `if_else`. (But really, `c+1899` seems more appropriate here.)

Comment: thanks all for your comments. I think I did not make my question more clear. I have edited it . Please check. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

- See, R is already vectorised.  There is no need to work iteratively in this scenario when your `new_column` uses same logic across the vector.
- Moreover, `==` is used as conditional and always return `TRUE` or `FALSE` or `NA`.  So please don't use it to assign values to any variable where `=` or `<-` or `->` should be used.

Do it like this

```
source <- 1:118

new_column <- source + 1899

> new_column
  [1] 1900 1901 1902 1903 1904 1905 1906 1907 1908 1909 1910 1911 1912 1913 1914 1915 1916 1917 1918 1919
 [21] 1920 1921 1922 1923 1924 1925 1926 1927 1928 1929 1930 1931 1932 1933 1934 1935 1936 1937 1938 1939
 [41] 1940 1941 1942 1943 1944 1945 1946 1947 1948 1949 1950 1951 1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 1959
 [61] 1960 1961 1962 1963 1964 1965 1966 1967 1968 1969 1970 1971 1972 1973 1974 1975 1976 1977 1978 1979
 [81] 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999
[101] 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017
```

for another new_column say `country` like previously you said, do

```
country <- paste('Country_', source)

> country
  [1] "Country_ 1"   "Country_ 2"   "Country_ 3"   "Country_ 4"   "Country_ 5"   "Country_ 6"  
  [7] "Country_ 7"   "Country_ 8"   "Country_ 9"   "Country_ 10"  "Country_ 11"  "Country_ 12" 
 [13] "Country_ 13"  "Country_ 14"  "Country_ 15"  "Country_ 16"  "Country_ 17"  "Country_ 18" 
 [19] "Country_ 19"  "Country_ 20"  "Country_ 21"  "Country_ 22"  "Country_ 23"  "Country_ 24" 
 [25] "Country_ 25"  "Country_ 26"  "Country_ 27"  "Country_ 28"  "Country_ 29"  "Country_ 30" 
 [31] "Country_ 31"  "Country_ 32"  "Country_ 33"  "Country_ 34"  "Country_ 35"  "Country_ 36" 
 [37] "Country_ 37"  "Country_ 38"  "Country_ 39"  "Country_ 40"  "Country_ 41"  "Country_ 42" 
 [43] "Country_ 43"  "Country_ 44"  "Country_ 45"  "Country_ 46"  "Country_ 47"  "Country_ 48" 
 [49] "Country_ 49"  "Country_ 50"  "Country_ 51"  "Country_ 52"  "Country_ 53"  "Country_ 54" 
 [55] "Country_ 55"  "Country_ 56"  "Country_ 57"  "Country_ 58"  "Country_ 59"  "Country_ 60" 
 [61] "Country_ 61"  "Country_ 62"  "Country_ 63"  "Country_ 64"  "Country_ 65"  "Country_ 66" 
 [67] "Country_ 67"  "Country_ 68"  "Country_ 69"  "Country_ 70"  "Country_ 71"  "Country_ 72" 
 [73] "Country_ 73"  "Country_ 74"  "Country_ 75"  "Country_ 76"  "Country_ 77"  "Country_ 78" 
 [79] "Country_ 79"  "Country_ 80"  "Country_ 81"  "Country_ 82"  "Country_ 83"  "Country_ 84" 
 [85] "Country_ 85"  "Country_ 86"  "Country_ 87"  "Country_ 88"  "Country_ 89"  "Country_ 90" 
 [91] "Country_ 91"  "Country_ 92"  "Country_ 93"  "Country_ 94"  "Country_ 95"  "Country_ 96" 
 [97] "Country_ 97"  "Country_ 98"  "Country_ 99"  "Country_ 100" "Country_ 101" "Country_ 102"
[103] "Country_ 103" "Country_ 104" "Country_ 105" "Country_ 106" "Country_ 107" "Country_ 108"
[109] "Country_ 109" "Country_ 110" "Country_ 111" "Country_ 112" "Country_ 113" "Country_ 114"
[115] "Country_ 115" "Country_ 116" "Country_ 117" "Country_ 118"
```

Comment: thanks @AnilGoyal . I have tried to be more specific in my edited question. please see.